# Piecewise function with $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{n}}$ and $\sqrt{1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}} + i \sqrt{-1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, complex-numbers, radicals, nested-radicals

**Problem**

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f(z) = z + \frac{1}{z}$. Given that
$$
f(z) = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{n}}     & \text{if } z \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace \\
\sqrt{1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}} + i \sqrt{-1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}}
                        & \text{if } z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
$$
for some positive integer $n$ and that $f(z^8) = 2023$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace$, find $n$.

- This problem is from the team round of a local high school math competition that has ended.

**My Work**

Interpretation 1: $z$ is a variable:

We know that $z^8$ is a real number, because the function keeps real numbers real and complex numbers complex.

So we have $f(z^8) = z^8 + \frac{1}{z^8}$ which is equal to the first part of the piecewise which is $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{n}}$.

We know that $2023 = z^8 + \frac{1}{z^8} = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{n}}$.

This does not make any sense. **I think that $z$ is actually just a constant and that $f(z) = z + \frac{1}{z}$ is not the definition for a function, but instead just an equation**.

Interpretation 2: $z$ is a constant or a complex constant

If $z$ was a real number, there would only be equation that we could use, $f(z) = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{n}}$. There is no way we can get anywhere with one equation. Therefore, $z$ is probably a complex number, so we are able to use three different equations.

Looking at the second part of the piecewise function, the only value of $n$ that could possible turn a complex number into a real number is $4$. So lets try investigating $n=4$.

If $n=4$, we know that $f(z) = \sqrt{2}$, so $z + \frac{1}{z}$ also equals $\sqrt{2}$. If we solve for z, we get two solutions, $z = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

After this, I am not sure how to continue. Nothing makes sense. I am not even sure if all of my previous steps are correct.

I would appreciate some help. Thank you!

Comment: Something looks me very odd : how can the first definition of $f$ be compatible with the second property with the two cases ? and with the third ?

Comment: Besides value $n=4$ could be interesting to investigate... because it annihilates the imaginary part in the second case

Comment: @JeanMarie Yeah... I am also really confused :(

I will investigate n=4, but why did you choose 4? Thank you for helping me!!

Comment: Let us forget the first definition $f(z)=z+1/z$. If you take almost any $z$, $z^8 \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$, therefore you are in the second case, and a direct way to have a real result, i.e., $2023$ is to annihilate the imaginary part $\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{n}/2}$, which is equivalent  $n=4$... What can we do, with this value of n, I haven't investigated yet...

Comment: @JeanMarie Makes sense, but if we plug in $n=4$, we end up with with $f(z) = \sqrt{2}$ if $z$ is complex, which contradicts the first definition.

Comment: I am confused ... defining a function of z in terms of n ??

Comment: @mick I am also really confused :(

Comment: The problem is very badly written. Once $f$ is defined, $z$ becomes an unknown quantity, like $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, then
$$\begin{align}&z+\frac 1z=\sqrt{2+\sqrt n}
\\\\&\implies z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}=\sqrt n
\\\\&\implies z^4+\frac{1}{z^4}=n-2
\\\\&\implies 2023=z^8+\frac{1}{z^8}=(n-2)^2-2
\\\\&\implies n-2=\pm 45
\\\\&\implies n=47\end{align}$$

If $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$, then
$$\begin{align}&z+\frac 1z=\sqrt{1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}} + i \sqrt{-1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}}
\\\\&\implies z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}=2i\sqrt{\frac{n}{4}-1}
\\\\&\implies z^4+\frac{1}{z^4}=-n+2
\\\\&\implies 2023=z^8+\frac{1}{z^8}=(-n+2)^2-2
\\\\&\implies -n+2=\pm 45
\\\\&\implies n=47\end{align}$$

So, it is necessary that $n=47$.

Since $n=47$ is sufficient, the answer is $\color{red}{47}$.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you.